# OpenCV with pthreads and mutexes

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, pthreads, mutex

I've written a fairly basic C++ program which uses OpenCV library to show an video steam for a IP camera I have.

Since I want to add image processing code in the future, I thought it would be a good idea to use threads to do it. One thread captures the most recent frame and the other thread reads this frame and displays it on screen. I used a `pthread_mutex_t` to lock the frame variable.

My problem is that the code actually compiles, but when I execute the program nothing happens, it just exists after couple of seconds. I've verified this is not a problem with the `VideoCapture` object, but I don't have any other idea why this does not work.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

//GLOBALS
VideoCapture vcap;
Mat frame;
pthread_mutex_t *frameLocker;

const string videoStreamAddress = "http://10.0.0.6/mjpg/video.mjpg";

void *Proc(void *arg)
{
    for(;;)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(frameLocker);
        vcap.read(frame);   
        pthread_mutex_unlock(frameLocker);
    }
}

int main(int, char**) { 
    frameLocker = new pthread_mutex_t();
    vcap.open(videoStreamAddress);

    pthread_mutex_init(frameLocker,NULL);   
    pthread_t *ProcThread;  
    pthread_create(ProcThread, NULL, Proc, NULL);


    for(;;)
    {               
        pthread_mutex_lock(frameLocker);
        imshow("Output Window", frame);         
        pthread_mutex_unlock(frameLocker);
    }

    delete frameLocker; 
}
```

I'd be glad if you could help me solve this issue.
Thanks,
Matan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

//GLOBALS
VideoCapture vcap;
Mat frame;
pthread_mutex_t frameLocker;

const string videoStreamAddress = "http://IP/mjpg/video.mjpg";

void *UpdateFrame(void *arg)
{
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat tempFrame;
        vcap >> tempFrame;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&frameLocker);
        frame = tempFrame;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&frameLocker);
    }
}

int main(int, char**) { 
    vcap.open(videoStreamAddress);

    pthread_mutex_init(&frameLocker,NULL);  
    pthread_t UpdThread;    
    pthread_create(&UpdThread, NULL, UpdateFrame, NULL);


    for(;;)
    {
        Mat currentFrame;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&frameLocker);
        currentFrame = frame;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&frameLocker);
        if(currentFrame.empty()){
            printf("recieved empty frame\n");
            continue;

        }


        imshow("Output Window", currentFrame);
        waitKey(1);
    }
}
```